# Vue Apollo Upload file crashes Node Maximum call stack size exceeded at _openReadFs

Tags: vue.js, graphql, upload, apollo, apollo-boost

I am trying to setup front end for graphQl file upload with Apollo-boost-upload. The backend code is based on this link
https://dev.to/dnature/handling-file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-14n7.
It's now reaching the resolver breakpoint after  adding  the following line in the server.js file

```
const { apolloUploadExpress } = require("apollo-upload-server");

app.use(apolloUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 1000000000, maxFiles: 10 }));
```

And after modifying the schema for the upload type

```
scalar Upload
```

Here is the Vue component

```html
 <input
    type="file"
    style="display:none"
    ref="fileInput"
    accept="image/*"
    @change="upload"
>
```

```js
//Upload method 
  upload({ target: { files = [] } }) {
        if (!files.length) {
          return;
        }
        this.logoImage = files[0];
      },

//Dispatching action from vue component

this.$store.dispatch("uploadLogo", { image: this.logoImage });

//Vuex action
const uploadLogo = async (context, payload) => {
  context.commit("setLoading", true);
  try {
    const { data } = await apolloClient.mutate({
      mutation: UPLOAD_LOGO,
      variables: {file: payload.image},
      context: {
        hasUpload: true,
      },
    });
    context.commit("setLoading", false);
    console.log("Logo:", data.uploadLogo);
  } catch (error) {
    context.commit("setLoading", false);
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Mutation
export const UPLOAD_LOGO = gql`
  mutation uploadLogo($file: Upload!) {
    uploadLogo(file: $file) {
      _id
      path
      filename
      mimetype
      user {
        _id
      }
    }
  }
`;


// Apolloclient config on main.js

import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost-upload";

import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-boost";
import VueApollo from "vue-apollo";


// Set up Apollo Client
export const defaultClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false,
  }),
 
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: "include",
  },
  request: (operation) => {
    // if no token in local storage, add it
    if (!localStorage.someToken) {
      localStorage.setItem("someToken", "");
    }
    // operation adds the token to authorizatrion header, which is sent o backend
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("someToken"),
      },
    });
  },
  onError: ({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (networkError) {
      console.log("[networkError]", networkError);
    }
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      for (const error of graphQLErrors) {
        console.dir(error);
        if (error.name === "AuthenticationError") {
          // set auth errir in state
          store.commit("setError", error);
          // signout user to clear error
          store.dispatch("signUserOut");
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Here is the updated typedef (old code commented out) from backend if that helps to identify the issue

```js
const logoUploadTypeDefs = gql`
  type File {
    _id: ID!
    path: String!
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    encoding: String!
    user: User
  }

  # input Upload {
  #   name: String!
  #   type: String!
  #   size: Int!
  #   path: String!
  # }

  scalar Upload

  type Mutation {
    uploadLogo(file: Upload!): File
  }
  type Query {
    info: String
    logo: File!
  }
`;
```

Now, the Node app crashes with the following  log

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec

Comment: @xadm Thanks, I have made some progress (see the updated question). It now reaches the resolver after some modifications on the front-end and backend. The uploaded file is reaching the backend. Now, I have another issue at the backend as indicated in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change "apollo-upload-server" to "graphql-upload"

**change 1:**

Commented out "apollo-upload-server" and used "graphql-upload"

```
// const { apolloUploadExpress } = require("apollo-upload-server");]
const {
  graphqlUploadExpress, // A Koa implementation is also exported.
} = require("graphql-upload");
```

And in the middleware, used this

**change 2:**

```
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
await apolloServer.start();
```

instead of old code

```
app.use(apolloUploadExpress());// Not to be used
await apolloServer.start();
```

Also, in the resolver, I added this

**change 3:**

Import Upload from graphql-upload in the resolver file

```
const { GraphQLUpload } = require("graphql-upload");

....
....

const resolvers = {
  // This maps the `Upload` scalar to the implementation provided
  // by the `graphql-upload` package.
  Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  Query: {
      ....
   }
  Mutations: {
      ....
  }

}
```

Refer to [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/) Docs for more details. This fixed the issue of Node crashing with error "Maximum call stack size exceeded at _openReadFs..."